# Jquery criar objeto contendo os dados do form

Tags: php, jquery

Ola preciso de uma ajuda , estou tentando criar um objeto contendo todos os dados de um formulario de perguntas/respostas.
 no php eu crio os radios assim :

```
<input type="radio" name="'.$row['id'].'" class="'.$row['id'].'" value="'.$row2['id'].'">&nbsp;'.utf8_encode($row2['resposta']).'<br>';
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

agora preciso pegar todos esses inputs e seus valores , detalhe :
a tabela que ira receber o resultado esta assim:

```
id|id_usuario|id_pesquisa|id_var|id_pergunta|id_resposta.
```

Agradeço se alguém conseguir me dar uma luz!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes criar um array com chave e valor associado exemplo:

```
var pesquisaArray = { 
id: $('input[name="id"]:checked').val(), // pegar valor de um radiobox
id_usuario: 200, 
id_pesquisa: $('#id_pesquisa').val() // valor com id id_pesquisa
//etc// 
};
```

podes modificar o valor de uma chave da seguinte forma:

```
pesquisaArray.id = 20;
```

ou

```
pesquisaArray["id"] = 20;
```

para fazeres um loop em todo o array podes utilizar a função [for in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

exemplo:

```
for (var chave in pesquisaArray) {
  console.log("chave " + key + " tem valor  " + pesquisaArray[chave]);
}
```

Comment: 13 dev, obrigado pelo retorno, isso auxiliou muito!! outra duvida, minhas tags names vem do id relacionado a pergunta do banco . como a cada questionário importado haverá novos id´s, os mesmo sempre serão diferentes. exite alguma forma de coletar o valor do id do input  sem saber seu id? ex: $('#1').val(); sei que esse id que quero acessar esta como um, mas caso nao soubesse o id, como pegaria ele ?

Comment: sim tem como, pela tag name: consulta este link https://stackoverflow.com/a/11945825/5244258, de nada se te ajudou dá up ^^